# Click matplotlib scatterplot point to display another graph based on point's meta data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, data-science

I have gotten [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52261010/11751799) to run on my machine, and it gave me an idea: instead of printing a string, can I show a new graph, based on the point's meta data?

To give an idea about my data, I have a SQL table with experiment names and results, and then I have another table with the entire procession of the experiment. It is easy to use `matplotlib` to graph either. I would like to create something interactive where I can plot the end results of the experiment (some kind of scatterplot), allowing the user to drill down deeper and view a graph of the entire experiment for the point clicked.

It seems like I should be able to modify the `on_pick` function to do plotting, as the following code shows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class custom_objects_to_plot:
    def __init__(self, x, y, name):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.name = name

a = custom_objects_to_plot(10, 20, "a")
b = custom_objects_to_plot(30, 5, "b")
c = custom_objects_to_plot(40, 30, "c")
d = custom_objects_to_plot(120, 10, "d")

def on_pick(event):
    plt.scatter([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]) # For the real function, run a SQL query to
                                      # get the data needed to do the plot of interest
    plt.title(event)
    plt.show()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for obj in [a, b, c, d]:
    artist = ax.plot(obj.x, obj.y, 'ro', picker=5)[0]
    artist.obj = obj

fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('pick_event', on_pick)

plt.show()
```

When I run this, I get an error: `QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running`.

Can `matplotlib` perform what I want to do?

(Eventually, the goal is to put this interactive graph in a `panel` browser window, but I am content right now just to run `matplotlib` from the command line.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to get a new figure to plot. All it requires are unique names in `on_pick`, not just `plt`, for the figure and axes.

```
def on_pick(event):
    my_fig, my_ax = plt.subplots() # New plot with unique name
    my_ax.scatter([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]) # Make the scatterplot
    my_fig.show() # Show the plot
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing everything almost fine, except that you don't need to create a new scatter, but rather update the old one. That's what your error is about. `plt.show()`'s loop is already running, and inside your callback, you're trying to launch it once more. Your callback should be like:

```py
def on_pick(event):
    plt.clf()  # It will clear previous scatter from figure
    plt.scatter([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8])
    plt.draw()  # It will tell pyplot to redraw
```

This would result into:
[image: Result]

Answer is provided, looking [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40434352/updating-matplotlib-plot-when-clicked)

Comment: If another SO question / answer, answer the new question, then the new question should be flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: +1 this is cool, but I think I do want to create a new plot, which I'm pretty sure I figured out how to do by calling a new `fix, ax` within the `on_pick` function. I might post a self-answer in the next few hours or days.